# Reactjs - redirect inside a function - not working

Tags: reactjs

I am working on a reactjs application. I am creating a user login page - and want to redirect the user to a home page or admin page - depending on their role -- but I am also trying to ensure that if a user already logged in - tries to go back to the login page - they get bounced back in similar logic.

When I try and put the "Redirect" parts inside a function - nothing happens.

Here is the current code base.

//login code

```
   var isAdmin = false;

    const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
    if(!user){

      if(this.props.authData.isLogged){
        const currentUser = JSON.stringify(this.props.authData);
        localStorage.setItem('user', currentUser);

        isAdmin = this.isLoggedInAnAdmin(this.props.authData);
        if(!isAdmin){
          return (
            <Redirect to="/home"/>
          )
        }else{
          return (
            <Redirect to="/admin"/>
          )
        }

      } 

      if(this.props.authData.data){
        //if error from server side show the message
        if(this.props.authData.data.data.status !== "success"){
          errorPlaceholder = this.props.authData.data.data.msg;
        }
      }
    }
    else{
      //redirect to home

      if(user){
        isAdmin = this.isLoggedInAnAdmin(user);
        if(!isAdmin){
          return (
            <Redirect to="/home"/>
          )
        }else{
          return (
            <Redirect to="/admin"/>
          )
        }
      }
    }
```

---

but if I place the redirect code in its own function - it never redirects?

```
  redirectUser(isAdmin){
        if(!isAdmin){
          return (
            <Redirect to="/home"/>
          )
        }else{
          return (
            <Redirect to="/admin"/>
          )
        }
  }
```

---

here is the login shell -- so it does a check to stash or read from the user localstorage.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { NavLink, withRouter, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { fetchAuthentication } from '../../actions/authAction';

import {persistStore} from 'redux-persist'

import { Row, Col } from 'antd';

// components
import LoginSyncValidationForm from './LoginSyncValidationForm'

import '../../forms.scss';

// this is a class because it needs state
class Login extends Component {

  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
    this.submit = this.submit.bind(this);
  }

  /*
  static propTypes = {
    isDark: React.PropTypes.bool
  }
  static defaultProps = {
    isDark: false
  }
  */

  componentDidMount() {
    //document.body.classList.toggle('darkClass', this.props.isDark)
  }
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    //document.body.classList.toggle('darkClass', nextProps.isDark)
  }

  componentWillMount () {
    document.body.classList.add('screenbackground');
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    document.body.classList.remove('screenbackground');
  }

  isLoggedInAnAdmin(user){
    //redirect if logged in already
    console.log("REDIRECT----", user);

      var isAdmin = false;
      if(user.data.data.data[0].role === "1"){
        isAdmin = true;
      }

      console.log("isAdmin----", isAdmin);
      return isAdmin;
  }

  redirectUser(isAdmin){

  }

  submit(data) {
    this.props.fetchAuthentication(data);
  }

  render() {
    // save object to localstorage as a string but you fetch it as a string
    // JSON.stringify(toLocalStorage) ============ JSON.parse(fromLocalStorage);
    // when the user has logged in - navigate them to the home page

    var errorPlaceholder = "";
    var isAdmin = false;

    const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
    //console.log("user already logged in", user);
    if(!user){

      if(this.props.authData.isLogged){
        //return <Redirect to='/home'/>;
        const currentUser = JSON.stringify(this.props.authData);
        localStorage.setItem('user', currentUser);
        //persistor.rehydrate()//calls reducer to rehydrate store

        isAdmin = this.isLoggedInAnAdmin(this.props.authData);
        if(!isAdmin){
          console.log("redirect y");
          return (
            <Redirect to="/home"/>
          )
        }else{
          console.log("redirect x");
          return (
            <Redirect to="/admin"/>
          )
        }

      } 

      if(this.props.authData.data){
        //if error from server side show the message
        if(this.props.authData.data.data.status !== "success"){
          errorPlaceholder = this.props.authData.data.data.msg;
        }
      }
    }
    else{
      //redirect to home
      //console.log("rediret to home");
      //const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
      console.log("user already logged in", user);
      console.log("LOGIN -- user", user);

      if(user){
        isAdmin = this.isLoggedInAnAdmin(user);
        if(!isAdmin){
          console.log("redirect y");
          return (
            <Redirect to="/home"/>
          )
        }else{
          console.log("redirect x");
          return (
            <Redirect to="/admin"/>
          )
        }
      }
    }


    return (
      <div className="Page form-components light">
        <h2>Login</h2>
        <Row>
          <Col xs={24} sm={24} md={10}>
            <p>Welcome to the SLAM SDQ tracker. Because you're accessing sensitive information, you need to confirm your identity using our secure login system. Your unique identification number has been sent to you by e-mail, please use it to login below.</p>
          </Col>
          <Col xs={24} sm={24} md={24}>
            <Row>
              <Col xs={24} sm={24} md={24}>
                <LoginSyncValidationForm onSubmit={this.submit} />
              </Col>
              <Col xs={24} sm={24} md={6}>
                <p><NavLink to="/forgot-password" activeClassName="selected">Forgotten your password?</NavLink> Not created an account yet? <NavLink to="/register-user" activeClassName="selected">Sign up</NavLink></p>
              </Col>
            </Row>
          </Col>
          {errorPlaceholder.length > 0 &&
            <Col xs={24} sm={24} md={12}>
              {errorPlaceholder}
            </Col>
          }
        </Row>
        <div className="shell" />
        <div className="screen-background login"/>
      </div>
    )
  }

}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    authData: state.auth
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
 return bindActionCreators({ fetchAuthentication }, dispatch);
}

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Login))
```

Comment: Have you showed the code that works or doesn't work? I can't tell easily. It helps if you can make your question concise, you could read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for some guidance on how to ask good questions. It's more work, but you may actually solve your problem in the process of simplifying it

Comment: well the code at the bottom works -- but reducing the repeating - redirect part -- is what I am trying to put in its own function - but when I do that -- it doesn't redirect.

Comment: its like the "redirect" stuff - needs to exist in the render part

Comment: -- I've just set a "flag" - that invokes the redirect -- in the render

Comment: I cant really see any example of you trying to do use the redirect from render. Did you try just adding  {this.redirectUser(userAdmin)}  ?

Comment: - yeah I did - it didn't work - its as if the redirect parts need to be inside the render part of the component - then be called from a function

Comment: yes for the redirect compnent to work it needs to be rendered. isnt that obvious?

Comment: - yes - but it doesn't work - if you invoke it from a function - it can't sit in a function, that gets invoked at render point

Comment: -- this works  -- http://jsfiddle.net/0ht35rpb/182/ -- this doesn't --  http://jsfiddle.net/0ht35rpb/183/  -- why @ReiDien

Comment: add return ```return this.redirectUser(isRedirect, isAdmin);```, and as an explanation. yes you returned a component on your redirectUser but does not have have anything to do with the returned value of render. unless you assign it to a variable and use it inside your ```return (...)``` then that would work. hope that helps you understand how obvious your problem was

Comment: Thank you for your advice. Sorry you have to end your comments with such sarcasm.